# A simple inequality about the $p$ norm

Tags: real-analysis

Take $f \in L^p(\lambda,(0,\infty))$, $1<p<\infty$ and define $F(x)=\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t) \, dt $, then how can we show:

$$\|F\|_p\leq \frac{p}{p-1}\|f\|_p.$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What is $\lambda$?

Comment: Lebesgue measure!

Comment: This is Hardy's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a proof using Minkowski inequality.

First notice that using the change of variable $t=sx$ we can rewrite
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_0^1 f(sx)ds.$$
Let's start the computation: by definition
$$\|F\|_p=\Big(\int_0^\infty \Big( \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt \Big)^pdx\Big)^{1/p}=\Big( \int_0^\infty \Big( \int_0^1 f(sx)ds \Big)^pdx\Big)^{1/p}$$
now by Minkowski integral inequality
$$\Big( \int_0^\infty \Big( \int_0^1 f(sx)ds \Big)^pdx\Big)^{1/p}\le\int_0^1\Big( \int_0^\infty f(sx)^p dx \Big)^{1/p}ds.$$
Hence, settin again $sx=t$,
$$\|F\|_p\le\int_0^1\Big( \int_0^\infty \frac{f(t)^p}{s} dt \Big)^{1/p}ds=\Big(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{s^{1/p}}ds \Big)\Big( \int_0^\infty f(t)^p  dt\Big)^{1/p}=\frac{p}{p-1}\|f\|_p.$$